# Process.waitFor() waits forever during mysql backup

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to use Process.waitFor() to wait until mysqldump finishes its backup process. Here is my code.

```
    ///i use this mysql command, its working fine
    String dump = "bkprefs/mysqldump "
            + "--host=localhost "       
            + "--port=3306 "
            + "--user=root "
            + "--password= "
            + "--add-drop-table "
            + "--add-drop-database "
            + "--complete-insert "
            + "--extended-insert "
            + "test";
    //execute the command
    Process run = null;
    try {
        run = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(dump);
        int stat = run.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The problem is that, `run.waitfor()` hangs. It seems like it keeps on waiting for something that will not happen.

When I replace the line `int stat = run.waitFor()` with `Thread.sleep(5)` the backup is working fine. But I can't stick to this because backing up time will vary depending on the size of the database so using `Thread.sleep` to wait for backup process to finish is not safe.

Please help me. Replies are greatly appreciated.

Edit :

I consume its inputstream using the following code.

```
    InputStream in = run.getInputStream();
    FileWriter fstream = null;
    try {
        fstream = new FileWriter("haha.sql");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

    int nextChar;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        while ((nextChar = in.read()) != -1) {
            out.write((char) nextChar);
            //sb.append((char) nextChar);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to consume the output streams from the sub process.  This [article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) details everything you need to do to use Process successfully.  (also, this has probably been answered many times on stackoverflow already).

Comment: The code that follows the code I just posted exactly does what your saying

Comment: @Bnrdo - are you using a _separate Thread_ to handle those streams (as detailed in that article)?

Comment: No, the code for handling those streams literally follows the backup code.

Comment: @Bnrdo - yes, which is exactly the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqldump` dumps to stdout. You might want read it the stream, or use option `-r` redirecting the output.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I edited my post so you see i read the the stream so I think that is not the issue to my question.